# Value is not showing up in the html file after variable is updated

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I can log to console the value that I get from a web service but it is not reflecting in my html. But if I use a debugger and I create breakpoint, I can see that my variable is filled up with a value and the html is updated but if I remove the debugger, the html is not updated. This happens on my site refresh. I am using IONIC 4. Please see my code below:

in my **.ts** file

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.connectionMessageSub = this.ss.connectionSubject$.subscribe(message => {
      this.connectionId = message;
      console.log(this.connectionId);
    });
}
```

in my **.html** file

```
<ion-item class="top" color="dark">
    <ion-label>{{connectionId}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks correct.Please try the above subscription in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: what is the output of that `console.log(this.connectionId)` without the debugger ? and can you please add the onError  callback method to your observable subscription to see if any errors are caught there?

Comment: Are you using ChangeDetection.OnPush?

Comment: @SellaDev I get the connectionId in the debugger;

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig ChangeDetection? Can you give me a sample Sir?

Comment: You can change the default behaviour of the change detection inside a component to a more performant one which requires some extra things in some cases. But if you haven't set that inside the component then don't worry about it.